# How to restrict SQLite db size to 2MB

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a local database and it can store n number of data's. I have to restrict the db limit to a maximum of 2 Mb. How it is possible? Please help me

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`getPath().length()`**

```
SQLiteDatabase _SQLITE_obj= getWritableDatabase();
long dbSIZE= new File(_SQLITE_obj.getPath()).length(); // Get Length
long dbSIZE_KB= dbSIZE/ 1024; //Convert to KB
long dbSIZE_MB= dbSIZE_KB/ 1024;  // KB to MB
```

**Now**

```
if (dbSIZE_MB> 2) 
{
 // Your logic
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PRAGMA max_page_count](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_max_page_count) to restrict the size of the database file (this depends on the [page size](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_page_size)).